# Which http request method for web API which receives big files

Tags: http, specifications, http-get

Which [http request method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) is suitable to receive big files?

My use case: I want to provide a HTTP API:

- Input: mp3 file. The whole file (not just the file name)
- Output: List of possible music interpreter singing this song.

Since no data gets modified on the server I think `POST` and `PUT` don't fit.

AFAIK the method `GET` does not fit:

- the mp3 file is too big for the query-string.
- GET-requests with data in the body are new to me.

Which http request method for web API which receives big files?

**Update**

- This is **not** an upload. The mp3 is the input, some text is the output.

**Update2**

Imagine you want to provide a HTTP API for `calculate_square_root()`. If you input `9` you receive `3`. Would you use the word "upload" for the number `9`? Where to draw a line between normal GET and big GET?

Comment: this is server-side where clients upload large files?  POST is the one you want to use for this, PUT is for replacing an existing resource rather than in your case you're using the uploaded file as input into some process which gives a result.

Comment: avoid bodies on GET, they are defined to have no meaning, and may be stripped or blocked.

Comment: @Adrien I update the question: "This is **not** an upload. The mp3 is the input, some text is the output."

Comment: Clarify *The mp3 is the input*. Won't you upload the file to the server?

Comment: If the client transmits a file to the server then it is uploading it. But in any case it's just input data for processing. POST is still the method. It doesn't HAVE to modify server state.

Comment: You should use `POST`.

Comment: you say there is no uploading, but clearly there is, the server receives the full file and processes it, so even if it's not being stored, it is being uploaded.

Comment: @Brian if you create a web API for `calculate_square_root()`, would you use the term "upload" for the number `9`. Would you use GET or POST? Where is the threshold?

Comment: i'd say sending a complete file is a good example of uploading.

Comment: @Brian for me it's no difference. It's a sequence of bytes.

Comment: this is getting ridiculous, but i'll go on: if you use the POST method, the number 9 can be stored as a variable in request.POST, whereas the mp3 file will be stored in request.FILES and requires a multipart form.

if that's not a difference i really don't know what is...

Comment: @Brian yes, it is ridiculous and fun. But you must not confuse cause and consequence. I am in the process of creating an API. The data will be in request.FILES if the API tells the client to do so.

Comment: ok i'll rephrase, the mp3 file SHOULD be stored in request.FILES, also, if you think about it, sending this number 9 is also uploading, after all you are sending data through the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the content of a file to the server, you should use a [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) request:

> [**4.3.3.  POST**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
>
> The `POST` method requests that the target resource process the
> representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's
> own specific semantics.  For example, `POST` is used for the following
> functions (among others):
>
> - Providing a block of data, such as the fields entered into an HTML
>   form, to a data-handling process;
>   [...]

The content of the file will be sent in the payload of the request and the [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) of the request should be set to [`multipart/form-data`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578).

Comment: Should POST be used for the API of `calculate_square_root()`?

Comment: @guettli Yes, `POST` can be used for that.

Answer (score 1):

For sending the large data like file contents you should use POST request.

For Uploading the file on the server side the 'Content-Type' of the request should be multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the RFC: [HTTP 1.1 Method Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) this seems to be a POST.

> The actual function performed by the POST method is determined by the server ...
>
> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource that can be identified by a URI. ...
>
> **If** a resource has been created on the origin server,...

The last two points seems to clearly support the idea that the server can just process the data and not store anything